# Django two websites hosted with Apache, urls do not work at one of them

Tags: django, windows, apache

I did set up two websites (hosted locally). I'm on windows so config may look odd.

```
WSGIPythonHome "C:/var/www/magazyn/env39"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/var/www/magazyn/venv/Lib/site-packages;C:/var/www/magazyn/rootkat/"

    ServerName www.magazyn-stolarz.pl
    LoadFile "C:/Python39/python39.dll"
    LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/var/www/magazyn/env39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
    WSGIScriptAlias /awizacje "C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat/awizacje/wsgi.py"
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/var/www/magazyn/rootkat/magazyn/wsgi.py"
    
    <Directory "C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat/awizacje/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /statica "C:/var/www2/static/"
    <Directory "C:/var/www2/static/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "C:/var/www/magazyn/rootkat/magazyn/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "C:/var/www/static/"
    <Directory "C:/var/www/static/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

With that configuration base site works perfectly `("pc-name/")` but the second one `("pc-name/awizacje")` does not. Main url works like it should but every button sends me to `("pc-name/button-url")` and not `("pc-name/awizacje/button-url")`. I have set `ROOT_URLCONF = 'awizacje.urls'` in `settings.py`. Is there something I am missing? Any way I should change settings to take base url into account?

Answer (score 0):

The problem were hardcodded urls. I changed it so it will use django urls into account.